# Resource Assignments

Tags: ms-project-2016

I have 4 Work resources entered into the Resource sheet and each has standard rates. I assign the work resources to tasks, but one of the tasks continues to display $0.00. Then when I double-click the task that has the 4 Work resources assigned, only 3 of the Work resources show cost values.